# Querying a table matching all the data of the subquery and all the data should also match with common data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables called "membership" and "restricted".

Table: **membership**

```
+---------+--------+
| GroupID | UserID |
+---------+--------+
|   10001 |    605 |
|   10001 |    255 |
|   10002 |    605 |
|   10004 |    222 |
|   10003 |    605 |
|   10002 |    501 |
+---------+--------+
```

Table: **restriction**
  Table called **restriction** is having the restricted GroupID and the corresponding ContentID to which the group is restricted.

```
+---------+-----------+
| GroupID | ContentId |
+---------+-----------+
|   10001 |     33333 |
|   10001 |     22222 |
|   10002 |     22222 |
|   10004 |     44444 |
|   10003 |     22222 |
|   10002 |     44444 |
+---------+-----------+
```

I want to get the ContentID that is of all the group the user id belong to from the restricted table.

ie. 
As in the sample data for UserID = 605, the group ids are "10001, 10002, 10003", i need to get the ContentID which is restricted for all the group id listed for user 605.

The expected ContentID in this case is '22222'.

The ultimate aim is to get the list of ContentID's which is restricted in all the group for that UserID. If the ContentID is not restricted in any one of the group then the contentID is no more considered as restricted.

Comment: SELECT ContentID FROM restricted WHERE GroupID IN ( SELECT GroupID FROM Membership WHERE UserID = 505 )

Comment: But here it is getting the record if it mactch any one of the group id since i am using IN

Comment: Set up a proper many to many relationship between members and groups and this task will be trivial.  If you don't understand what I just said, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Here we do not have any ORM to handle it as an object as Many to many.  It is an legacy  application where it has been written with plain SQL query.

Comment: @user4130072 You should edit your question with the query you put in comments.

Comment: @user4130072 did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Best I can do without knowing the table structures:

```
Select ContentID, *
From [DatabaseName].dbo.Members M
JOIN [DatabaseName].dbo.Restricted R on R.GroupID = M.GroupID
WHERE M.GroupID = 505
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.userid, R.contentid
FROM restriction R
INNER JOIN membership M
    ON M.groupid = R.groupid
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT groupid) FROM membership M2 WHERE M2.userid = M.userid) =
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT groupid) FROM restriction R2 WHERE R2.contentid = R.contentid)
```

returns:

```
UserId  ContentId
------  --------- 
255     33333    
605     22222
```